# List index out of range : Python :

Tags: python

So I have a list named "enemy_pos". Inside that, I have another 2 lists. When I try to change a number from one of that 2 lists it says "list index out of range"

Here is my code:

```
enemy_pos = [[0, -2, -12], [0, -1, -12]]
enemy_speed = 0.2

def move():
    for i in range(2):
        enemy_pos[[i][1]] -= enemy_speed
```

Comment: What do you think this mean `enemy_pos[[i][1]]`?

Comment: right syntax `enemy_pos[i][1]`

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan `enemy_pos[[i][1]]` even this is right syntax.Example `a=[1,2,3,4,5];a[[1,2,3][0]]--->2`

Comment: @Ch3steR really

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan `list.__getitem__` takes integers as input it doesn't care they come from. Try this `

Comment: @Ch3steR thanks for clearing that out.

Comment: Oh, yeah, thanks. I just saw that [[i][1]] was the right format on the internet.

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan Not a problem. [check here](https://repl.it/repls/SkyblueAnimatedProgrammingmacro). You answered what OP needed, I was just saying it's correct syntax

Comment: @Yenz1 Maybe it wasn't for *Python*. Or they just posted *pseudo-code*. The correct way is mentioned down in the answers. Happy learning. And Welcome to SO. ;)

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Comment: Also, I'm voting to close this, I can't see it being relevant in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  extra square bracket after `enemy_pos` in the last line is not required. It should be `enemy_pos[i][1]`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having is because `enemy_pos[[i][1]]` means
`Get the element from enemy_pos at index [i][1]`, where `[i][1]` means get the element at index 1 from the list `[i]`. However, `[i]` only has an element at index 0, which is why you're getting `List index out of range`.

The correct syntax for accessing elements from nested arrays is:

```py
enemy_pos[i][1]
```

Loosely speaking, it means, get the list from enemy_post at index `i`, and from that list, get the element at index 1.

Hope this helps